INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION Error when downloading my app from Google Play
I'm experiencing an issue with my Android Capacitor app where I get the error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION when attempting to install it after uploading the Android App Bundle (AAB) to Google Play.
Here's the situation:
The app runs perfectly when I test it on both the emulator and a physical device.
I can also generate an APK manually and install it on my phone without any problems.
I also tried generating the AAB, converting it to an APK, and installing that APK on the device, and it works flawlessly.
However, when I upload the AAB to Google Play and try to install the app from there, I encounter the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION error. This happens across different devices; none can successfully download and install my app from Google Play due to this issue.
What I've tried:

I made sure to clean and rebuild my project before generating the AAB. I also tried to remove the Android and node_modules folders and started again but the issue is still happening.

I looked for any potential issues in my AndroidManifest.xml, but everything seems to be in order:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

This is my build.grandle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace "my.app.id"
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.1.0a"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}

These are the target SDK versions for my app:
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.8.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.6.1'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.12.0'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.6.2'
    coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.1'
    androidxWebkitVersion = '1.9.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.5'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.5.1'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
}

This is the error displayed in my pre-launch report:

If anyone has encountered this issue or has insights on what might be causing this error, I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thank you!

I'm also having this issue. I've uploaded a Flutter app. Works fine in all debug modes and side loading.

Yeah, it's really strange, and the solutions I found online didn't fix it. Could this be a new issue?

Apparently it's a problem with Google's new game optimization.
Switching off Setup > Advanced settings > App optimization in Google Play solves the issue.

This worked for me but I'm deploying an app. So it was app optimization.
